# Help required with size of the symbol

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, flex, arcgis-flex-viewer

I am adding a picture marker symbol to graphic layer like this in Map click event:

```
const mapPoint:MapPoint = map.toMapFromStage(event.stageX, event.stageY);
mapPoint.spatialReference = map.spatialReference;
geom= mapPoint;

[Embed(source='assets/images/globe.png')]
var picEmbeddedClass:Class;

var pictureMarker:PictureMarkerSymbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol(picEmbeddedClass,100,100);

var myGraphicPic:Graphic = new Graphic(geom);
myGraphicPic.symbol = pictureMarker;
graphicsLayer.add(myGraphicPic);
```

which works fine. When I zoom in and zoom out it maintains its `width=100 height=100` upon every change in zoom level to adjust its size.

How to make it retain its size as it was while adding it to graphics layer, irrespective of zoom level. As I zoom in it may seem bigger to me and small as I zoom out.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do so, using a symbol. What you could do, is to create a polygon at that location, according to your image. It will expand and contract as you zoom in & out

Comment: You mean to say rather than creating map points I should create a polygon? Can you please explain further or paste an example.

Comment: I had posted another question please look at that and suggest. It is here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15792/help-needed-for-extended-symbol

Comment: Can I accomplish the same by extending ESRI's Graphics class?

Comment: Yes, create a polygon graphic (say a circle) at the location of the map click, and add it to the graphic layer.

Comment: Polygons need a symbol to render like Simple Fill Symbol and can only create angular shapes like Triangles. I want to create arcs and other complex shapes that contact and expand as Polygon does, please guide me a way.

Comment: I had extended Symbol class in order to accomplish this and drawn lines and arcs on it using Degrafa. They also behave them same as Picture Marker Symbol does. Please guide me.